# Solr cannot be deployed in tomcat6

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, tomcat6

I have tomcat6 installed and running on Ubuntu. When I copy `solr.war` to `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr.war`, the `/solr` path appears in tomcat manager.

**Problem:** However when I add `solr.xml` to `/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml`, `/solr` path disappears in tomcat manager. Looking into `catalina.out`:

```
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:17 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 496 ms
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ROOT.xml
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive solr.war
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig init
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context [/solr] 
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:150)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:87)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:66)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:86)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:886)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:1021)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4449)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr.war
    at org.apache.naming.resources.WARDirContext.setDocBase(WARDirContext.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4320)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/solr] startup failed due to previous errors
Oct 9, 2012 7:24:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext stop
INFO: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/solr] has not been started
```

**Solr.xml**

```
<Context path="/solr" docBase="/usr/share/solr"
   debug="0" privileged="true" allowLinking="true" crossContext="true">
  <!-- make symlinks work in Tomcat -->
  <Resources className="org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext" allowLinking="true" />

  <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/usr/share/solr" override="true" />
</Context>
```

Any idea what seems to be the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a context to change the docBase for any webapp (let alone Solr), you need to make sure those directories and files exist.  Either move them there where you want to point to, or recreate them there.

What is your reason to change the docBase?  To separate it from the Tomcat Install. If not, I would just leave it there and if you want Solr to reference it's data directory for indexing and data, you can pass it as a system parameter or a change in solrconfig.xml

Comment: I fixed the problem! There's no need to have that solr.xml file. Just drop in the solr.war file, copy the solr examples directory, and it works now.